# Remove trailing whitespace before saving into the command history

Tags: zsh, command-history

When I paste a command to the terminal, sometimes it ends with some newline or space characters depending on where I copied from. The trailing whitespace characters are typically useless (they don’t mean anything from the shell point of view), so showing them in completion is useless. I thought that [the Zsh option `hist_reduce_blanks`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HIST_005fREDUCE_005fBLANKS) should do the trick, but it seems to only remove whitespaces between words. Any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Zsh hook called [`zshaddhistory`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-zshaddhistory):

```
function zshaddhistory() {
    setopt local_options extended_glob
    print -Sr -- ${1%%[[:space:]]##}
    return 1  # suppress default behavior
}
```

Corresponding Zsh manuals:

- [`print` built-in](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)
- [Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)
- [`extended_glob` option](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB)

Caveat: Zsh (unlike Bash) has a special buffer to keep “last command” which is separate from the history. This hook won’t affect that buffer.